# PHP get url with special characters without urlencode:ing them!

Tags: php, urlencode, file-get-contents

I would like file_get_contents to get a url that looks like this: [http://wapedia.mobi/sv/Gröt](http://wapedia.mobi/sv/Gr%C3%B6t)

The problem is that it requests (can't post entire link, sorry): ...wapedia.mobi/sv/Gr%C3%B6t which you can see has been urlencoded, that page does not give me any results.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [PHP manua](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)l, you must specifically encode a URL if it contains special characters.  This means the function itself should do no special encoding.  Most likely your URL is being encoded *before* being passed to the function, so pass it through `urldecode` first and see what happens.

**Edit:**  You're saying the encoding is being messed up.  Again the PHP manual specifically states that you need to encode urls prior to passing them to `file_get_contents`.  Try encoding the URL, then passing it to the function.

```
$url = urlencode($url);
file_get_contents($url);
```

Comment: wapedia.mobi/sv/Gr%C3%B6t

was actually working. Sorry, but my PHP script is requesting: Gr%F6t. Why is that? And how can I encode (Gröt) it so it ends up beeing: Gr%C3%B6t.

Thank you so much.

Comment: I fixed the problem. It originated from the JavaScript function that passed the string as a GET argument to the PHP file. So I guess this wasn't a PHP question after all, sorry about that.

I originally encoded it with the JavaScript escape() function, however, I found that using encodeURIComponent was working much better with UTF-8.

Thank you very much for your time and help.

Comment: thanks Johan, your suggestion to use 'encodeURIComponent' worked for me!