# Pass url with character %20 as ajax variable

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, url

I need to pass a url to a php page. the url may or may not contain special characters and encoded variables.
for example consider the ajax request.

```
var url = 'http://siteaddr.com/abc%20cdf%202012%20movies%20software/';
$.get('check_link.php',{url:url},function(){
    //some function
});
```

the echo result of variable `$_GET['url']` in the php page is `http://siteaddr.com/abc cdf 2012 movies software/`
the %20's are converted into spaces. I need to receive the url as it is.
tried encoding and decoding the url. but I didn't got the result as i need.

Comment: [URL encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) it! Or is it what you already did?

Comment: by encoding it, I will receive the whole url encoded right.
so i must decode it at the php page.
by decoding, it decodes the %20 in the url too...
thats y I need some alternative..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1174189/php-get-url-with-special-characters-without-urlencodeing-them

Comment: that is url encode of `http://siteaddr.com/abc%20cdf%202012%20movies%20software/` results `http%3A%2F%2Fsiteaddr.com%2Fabc%20cdf%202012%20movies%20software%2F` while decoding it results `http://siteaddr.com/abc cdf 2012 movies software/` which loses the %20.

Comment: What if you do `$url = urlencode($_GET['url']);`? Alternatively, you could use `preg_replace()`

Comment: %20 is just a single condition...
there must be many more special encoded variables will be there in the url right?
so its practically possible to do that for all?

Comment: You want the `%20` and other entities kept intact within your submitted url ? May we know the specific reason for keeping the encodings at server side? If so, we might be able to suggest something else.

Comment: i need to just check whether the entered url is there in my database.

Answer (score 0):

1. You're not supposed to define a variable with the name that will be used as a key.
2. Encoding the URL again, before sending it will make PHP decode the double encoded URL.

   ```
   var link = 'http://siteaddr.com/abc%20cdf%202012%20movies%20software/';
   $.get('check_link.php',{url: encodeURIComponent(link)}, function(){
       //some function
   });
   // Double encoded URL: Note that % has become %25
   // http%3A%2F%2Fsiteaddr.com%2Fabc%2520cdf%25202012%2520movies%2520software%2F
   ```

http://jsfiddle.net/zNqac/