# file_get_contents - Special characters in URL - Special case

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding, file-get-contents

I'm not getting file_get_contents() to return the page in this particular case where the url contains an 'Ö' character.

```
$url = "https://se.timeedit.net/web/liu/db1/schema/s/s.html?tab=3&object=CM_949A11_1534_1603_DAG_DST_50_ÖVRIGT_1_1&type=subgroup&startdate=20150101&enddate=20300501"
print file_get_contents($url);
```

How do I make file_get_contents() work as expected on this url?

I have tried following solutions whithout a working result:

1.

```
print rawurlencode(utf8_encode($url));
```

2.

```
print mb_convert_encoding($url, 'HTML-ENTITIES', "UTF-8");
```

3.

```
$url = urlencode($url);
print file_get_contents($url);
```

4.

```
$content = file_get_contents($url);
print mb_convert_encoding($content, 'UTF-8', mb_detect_encoding($content, 'UTF-8, ISO-8859-1', true));
```

Found in these questions:

[file_get_contents - special characters in URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10396777/file-get-contents-special-characters-in-url)

[PHP get url with special characters without urlencode:ing them!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1174189/php-get-url-with-special-characters-without-urlencodeing-them)

[file_get_contents() Breaks Up UTF-8 Characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236668/file-get-contents-breaks-up-utf-8-characters)

UPDATE:
As you can see a page is actually returned in my example but it is not the expected page, the one you get when you type the url in the browser.

Comment: You might want to take a quick look at the following link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236668/file-get-contents-breaks-up-utf-8-characters

Comment: @HomelessPerson As I wrote in the question I have already seen that question, could you point out the relevant part for my case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**URLs cannot contain "Ö"!** Start from this basic premise. Any characters not within a narrowly defined subset of ASCII must be URL-encoded to be represented within a URL. The right way to do that is to `urlencode` or `rawurlencode` (depending on which format the server expects) the individual segment of the URL, **not the URL as a whole**.

E.g.:

```
$url = sprintf('https://se.timeedit.net/web/liu/db1/schema/s/s.html?tab=3&object=%s&type=subgroup&startdate=20150101&enddate=20300501',
               rawurlencode('CM_949A11_1534_1603_DAG_DST_50_ÖVRIGT_1_1'));
```

You will still need to use the correct encoding for the string! `Ö` in ISO-8859-1 would be URL encoded to `%D6`, while in UTF-8 it would be encoded to `%C3%96`. Which one is the correct one depends on what the server expects.

Answer (score 1):

One needs to percentage encode the unicode characters. This is one way that I know of doing it.

```
$url2 = "https://se.timeedit.net/web/liu/db1/schema/s/s.html?tab=3&object=" . urlencode('CM_949A11_1534_1603_DAG_DST_50_ÖVRIGT_1_1') . "&type=subgroup&startdate=20150101&enddate=20300501";
echo "encoded: " . $url2;
print file_get_contents($url2);
```