# print file_get_content gives special characters in url, php

Tags: php, character-encoding, file-get-contents

I want to print an image url, but it gives me special characters. I tried every solution in [file_get_contents - Special characters in URL - Special case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31720418/file-get-contents-special-characters-in-url-special-case) but it didnt solve it.

my code:

```
$urlgeo = "http://geodata.nationaalgeoregister.nl/top25raster/wms?request=GetMap&service=WMS&version=1.3.0&request=GetMap&layers=top25raster&styles=&bbox=146000,451000,149000,454000&width=600&height=600&srs=EPSG:28992&format=image/png";
print file_get_contents($urlgeo);
```

Comment: You can base64 encode it, like `... base64_encode(file_get_contents($urlgo));`

Comment: You're not printing the URL, you're printing the content.

Comment: This gives also special characters instead of my image url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to show the image try this:

```
<?php
$urlgeo = "http://geodata.nationaalgeoregister.nl/top25raster/wms?request=GetMap&service=WMS&version=1.3.0&request=GetMap&layers=top25raster&styles=&bbox=146000,451000,149000,454000&width=600&height=600&srs=EPSG:28992&format=image/png";
echo "<img src='data:image/png;base64," . base64_encode(file_get_contents($urlgeo)) . "'>";

?>
```

It gets the image and encodes in base64.

And later if you need the raw image data, just `base64_decode` it like:

```
$raw_image = base64_decode($encodedImg):
```

Where `$encodedImg` is the base64 encoded string. The `$raw_imag` would contain the raw image data!

Comment: CAUTION: You should note that this solution makes you store in your server memory a potentially huge block of image data (thanks to base 64 encoding)

Comment: Yeah, then you can asynchronously load the image using AJAX!

Answer (score 2):

You are requesting an PNG Image from the API service, you should use the appropriate headers to display the image,

```
header('Content-Type: image/png'); 
$urlgeo = "http://geodata.nationaalgeoregister.nl/top25raster/wms?request=GetMap&service=WMS&version=1.3.0&request=GetMap&layers=top25raster&styles=&bbox=146000,451000,149000,454000&width=600&height=600&srs=EPSG:28992&format=image/png";
print file_get_contents($urlgeo);
```